# Realmente é necessário colocar "text/javascript" na tag <script>?

Tags: javascript, html

Estamos em 2016. Já li em alguns lugares na internet que não é mais necessário utilizar essa declaração `type="text/javascript"`. De fato, utilizar a tag `script` sem declarar esse trecho não afeta em nada o funcionamento do Javascript.

Mas, mesmo assim, ainda em IDEs atualizadas (como por exemplo o Sublime Text 3), o mecanismo de autocompletamento faz com que a tag `<script>` seja declarada com `type="text/javascript"`.

Gostaria de saber se é seguro deixar de usar `text/javascript`.

Algumas IDEs ainda colocam por questão de compatibilidade?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Na versão **HTML 4.x**, o atributo `type` é obrigatório ([W3](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/scripts.html#adef-type-SCRIPT)).

> This attribute specifies the scripting language of the element's
>   contents and overrides the default scripting language. The scripting
>   language is specified as a content type (e.g., "text/javascript").
>   **Authors must supply a value for this attribute. There is no default
>   value for this attribute.**

Grifo: "Criadores devem preencher o valor desse atributo, não existe um valor padrão para ele."

Já no HTML 5, o atributo é **opcional**, se você não definir o padrão será `text/javascript` ([W3](https://dev.w3.org/html5/pf-summary/semantics.html#attr-script-type))

> The type attribute gives the language of the script or format of the
>   data. If the attribute is present, its value must be a valid MIME
>   type. The charset parameter must not be specified. **The default, which
>   is used if the attribute is absent, is "text/javascript"**.

Grifo: O valor padrão caso o atributo esteja ausente é: "text/javascript".

Comment: O segundo link está quebrado

Comment: Link atualizado! :)

Answer (score 11):

Complementando, o atributo `type="text/javascript"` (padrão do HTML 4) se tornou obsoleto em abril de 2006 (há mais de 10 anos desta pergunta) segundo o [RFC 4329](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4329.txt), sendo substituído a partir de então por:

- `application/javascript` ou
- `application/ecmascript`

Que eram necessários para navegadores mais antigos da época (ex., IE8). Em navegadores ainda mais antigos, usava-se o atributo `language="javascript"`, que foi totalmente descontinuado.

Se você usa HTML5, não faz sentido usar o `type`, já que navegadores pré-modernos não são compatíveis com esta especificação do HTML.