# Meu primeiro código Javascript não funciona. E agora?

Tags: javascript, html5

Estou tentando rodar meu primeiro javascript. Mas ao clicar no botão que criei, o texto que deveria aparecer na tela não aparece. Onde estou errando?
Meu navegador é atualizado então deve rodar Javascript 1.8.5. Mesmo assim tentei até setando a versão 1.1 e não funciona igual...

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 5.0//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd">
<HTML>
<HEAD> 
<TITLE>Menu</TITLE>
    <script language = "JavaScript1.8.5">
        function teste1(){
            document.write("<h1>Teste1 foi acionado!!!</h1>")
            var teste = new Object();
            teste.x = 2,4;
            teste.y = 5;
            document.write(teste.x)
    </script>
</HEAD> 
<BODY>
    <input type="button" value="Teste 1" onClick="teste1()">
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.body.innerHTML += "<h1>Teste1 foi acionado!!!</h1> ";
```

Faltou o fecha aspa.

E o script fica no Body

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 5.0//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd">
<HTML>
<HEAD> 
<TITLE>Menu</TITLE>
</HEAD> 
<BODY>
    <input type="button" value="Teste 1" onClick="teste1()">
    <script>
        function teste1(){
            document.body.innerHTML += "<h1>Teste1 foi acionado!!!</h1>";
            var teste = new Object();
            teste.x = 2,4;
            teste.y = 5;
            document.body.innerHTML += teste.x;
        }
    </script>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Funcionou! Mas parece que o script não para de rodar nunca, pois a página do navegador fica "carregando" pra sempre.  Como pode ver, eu coloquei o </script> no final...

Comment: Devo discordar sobre a afirmação logo no começo da resposta? Não vejo falta de fechamento de aspas, nem no histórico da pergunta. Vi outros ajustes no código e o que percebi que ajudou de fato (posso estar enganado) foi o fecha chaves da função `}`, como o dvd colocou na outra resposta

Answer (score 3):

Não se usa mais o atributo `language` há muito tempo (**[veja esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/270629/8063)**). Use apenas:

```
<script>
    // código
<script>
```

A versão do JavaScript é definida pelo navegador que você usa. Se usa um navegador atual, irá rodar o JavaScript mais moderno. Não há necessidade de setar uma versão na tag, até porque irá retornar erro.

Além do que faltou fechar a função com a chave de fechamento `}`.