# Qual a diferença entre usar type="text/javascript" ou não?

Tags: javascript, html5

Estou estudando **Boostrap 4** e em uma das aulas ao configurar um `carousel` reparei com a adição do `type="text/javascript"` ao meu `<script>`, a duvida é a seguinte, qual é a função de passar esse **type** e existe alguma vantagem nisso ?

Pois mesmo não passando parâmetro o código responde da mesma forma.

**Por exemplo:**

```
<!-- Com type -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.carousel').carousel({
        interval:1000
    })
</script>
<!-- Sem Type -->
<script>
    $('.carousel').carousel({
        interval:1000
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Até o HTML4 era preciso, agora com o HTML5 não mais, ficou é opcional, até para manter a compatibilidade:

https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#attr-script-type

> The type attribute gives the language of the script or format of the
>   data. If the attribute is present, its value must be a valid MIME
>   type. The charset parameter must not be specified. **The default, which
>   is used if the attribute is absent, is "text/javascript"**.

Ou seja, se não tiver, o padrão assumido é "text/javascript"

Aqui uma pergunta relacionada: [Realmente é necessário colocar “text/javascript” na tag ?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/168460/57220)