# não consigo linkar, o arquivo html com o estilo css

Tags: html, html5, css3

Boa noite. estou tentando linkar um arquiv.html com um outro arquivo.css para que eu possa utilizar o estilo css na minha pagina html através de uma id só que, mesmo com a tag correta não estou conseguindo fazer isso.

html:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="pt-br">

   <head>
      <title>d</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">

      <!-- Normalize CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" Type=text/css" href="css/normalize.css">

      <!-- Estilo customizado -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" Type=text/css" href="css/estilo.css">

       <!--[if IE]>
          <script src"htpp://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js></script>
          <![endif] -->
   </head>

   <body>
      <div id="box"> 
       <h1>lorem ipsum</h1>
        <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed a nunc eu erat vulputate commodo et eu turpis. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Etiam consectetur risus posuere dui faucibus fermentum. Maecenas iaculis, purus in laoreet finibus, libero mi sollicitudin enim, sed dapibus arcu nibh eu lorem. Mauris vitae lorem in ex condimentum tristique nec id est. Pellentesque et urna nec justo cursus aliquam. Fusce et libero vel massa condimentum ornare a id elit.
       </p>
     </div>     
   </body>

</html>
```

css:

```
#box{
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background: #b9c941;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
```

link do projeto: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/68hsu4mretsawfc/AABE7ogj6jO0HSGBuNFUFeUVa?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá. Na tag link você está escrevendo o atributo `type` com letra maiúscula. Assim vai funcionar:
`<link rel="stylesheet" type=text/css" href="css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type=text/css" href="css/estilo.css">`

Comment: Lucas sem ofensas, mas nem de `type` precisa... vc pode testar ai só colocando `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilo.css">` que vc vai ver que funciona. Para tag Script tb não se usa mais o atributo type. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/168460/realmente-%C3%A9-necess%C3%A1rio-colocar-text-javascript-na-tag-script . O problema dele deve ser outro

Comment: o problema foi em passar um atributo inválido